# Hierarchical Tree Table (sql) Query from one table

Tags: sql, recursion, sybase, sap-ase

### Situation

I have a table the contains partnumbers that are in a hierarichal tree structure.
***partno*** is the parent and ***partno_item*** is the child however this changes as the child can become the parent of another part and moves to the ***partno*** column.

The table looks basically as follows (I left out some columns as well the first which contains the internal unique key)

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╗
║ partno  ║ partno_item ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╣
║ 123-01  ║ 1234-01     ║
║ 123-01  ║ 1234-02     ║
║ 123-01  ║ 1234-03     ║
║ 1234-03 ║ 1234-04     ║
║ 1234-04 ║ 1234-05     ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╝
```

I would like to search for a specific part and have all its children and grandchildren shown.
In this case I search for 123-01 and I would like to get a result similar to this.
Preferable with an additional column that shows you the level in the hierarchy

```
╔═════════════╦═══════╗
║ partno_item ║ level ║
╠═════════════╬═══════╣
║ 1234-01     ║     1 ║
║ 1234-02     ║     1 ║
║ 1234-03     ║     1 ║
║ 1234-04     ║     2 ║
║ 1234-05     ║     3 ║
╚═════════════╩═══════╝
```

How can I achieve this with a query?

---

Update: RDBMS is Sybase ASE

Comment: You should state which Sybase product you are using (ASE, Anywhere, IQ) as the SQL functions vary between products

Answer (score 1):

This procedure `getItems` should do what you want:P
[See code](https://gist.github.com/csaar95/6a1fb07cf49a6dee7624f909aa67990d)

The result looks like this:

```
partno  partno_item
123-01  1234-01
123-01  1234-02
123-01  1234-03
1234-03 1234-04
1234-04 1234-05
123-02  1234-06
partno_item     lvl
1234-01 1
1234-02 1
1234-03 1
1234-04 2
1234-05 3
```

---

**Edit:** Moved the code into the answer

```sql
-- src table
create table #src(
  partno      varchar(10),
  partno_item varchar(10)
)

insert #src(partno, partno_item) values('123-01', '1234-01')
insert #src(partno, partno_item) values('123-01', '1234-02')
insert #src(partno, partno_item) values('123-01', '1234-03')
insert #src(partno, partno_item) values('1234-03', '1234-04')
insert #src(partno, partno_item) values('1234-04', '1234-05')
insert #src(partno, partno_item) values('123-02', '1234-06')

select * from #src
go


-- get items
create procedure getItems
  @partno     varchar(10)
as
  declare
    @lvl      int

  select @lvl = 1

  -- tmp table
  create table #tmp(
    partno_item varchar(10),
    lvl         int
  )

  if exists(
    select partno from #src where (partno = @partno)
  ) begin
    insert #tmp(partno_item, lvl)
    select distinct partno_item, @lvl from #src where (partno = @partno)

    while exists(
      select distinct s.partno_item
      from #src s, #tmp t
      where (t.lvl = @lvl)
        and (t.partno_item = s.partno)
    ) begin
      select @lvl = @lvl + 1    -- increase lvl

      insert #tmp(partno_item, lvl)
      select distinct s.partno_item, @lvl
      from #src s, #tmp t
      where (t.lvl = @lvl - 1)
        and (t.partno_item = s.partno)
    end
  end

  select * from #tmp
  truncate table #tmp
  drop table #tmp
go


-- exec
exec getItems '123-01'
go


truncate table #src
drop table #src
drop procedure getItems
go
```

Comment: please post your code into the answer; external links are generally discouraged (eg, 3 yrs from now this question/answer still exists but the external link is broken/missing)